# How does it work List index L[L[index]]

Tags: python, list, indexing

Hi all I recently stepped over a indexing of a list i had never seen and do not understand. `List[List[index]]`

example

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]

in: L[0]

out: 1

in: L[L[0]]

out: 2
```

Why is that? Why using L removes the first element?

I understand if L would have list as elements but in this case?

Thank you all for the support given to a rookie :)

Answer (score 8):

Not sure why you are confused, it is pretty simple

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]
L[0] == 1 
L[L[0]] == L[1] == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This may make more sense when using two separate lists.

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
L2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Indexing the zeroth element of L1 gives

```
L[0]
# returns:
1
```

If you use that value as an index for `L2`, you will get back the index=1 value.  The following two inputs are equivalent.

```
L2[1]
# returns:
'b'

L2[L1[0]]
# returns
'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

So, we have `L = [1,2,3,4,5].`

You need to remember that python list indices start from 0

```
input: L[0]    #0 is the index
output: 1
```

So, now when you do `L[L[0]], it is actually L[1], because L[0] = 1`

So `L[1] is 2.`

Another example, by trying with different index

```
L[L[2]] = L[3] = 4 , because L[2] = 3
```